# Why doesnt this regex match up to the first character specified?

Tags: regex

I have...

```
"Data Source=MYSERVER.dghdev.ds;Initial Catalog=CarPath;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Password1"
```

And I wrote the regular expression...

```
(?=Data Source).*;
```

But it matches everything up to 'sa'. Which is really annoying I just dont understand why this happens. The .* says any amount of characters and then the ';' should stop at the first one. It doesnt it stops at the fourth one. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

Comment: `.*` is greedy, and it will only stop if the next `;` is the last `;` in the string.

Comment: ``*`` opearator always by default is greedy, to make it lazy put a ``?`` after your pattern.

Answer (score 3):

`*` quantifier is greedy, and it will match as many characters as possible until it cannot match the next token and has to backtrack. In this case, `.*` will match everything up to the last `;` in the string.

If you want to stop at the first `;`, you need the lazy version of the quantifier: `*?`. In other words, your regex should be `(?=Data Source).*?;`. The lazy quantifier will try to match as few character as possible, as long as the next token can be matched.

***Depending on the support of the language***, the behavior of quantifiers such as `*`, `+`, `{n,m}` generally can be made lazy by adding `?` right after `*?`, `+?`, `{n,m}?`.